# Is there an R equivalent of SAS PROC FREQ?

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics, sas

Does anyone know of an R equivalent to SAS `PROC FREQ`?

I am trying to generate summary descriptive statistics for multiple variables at once.

Comment: Why was this question closed? It relates to data visualization and generated several worthwhile responses.

Answer (score 12):

I use `table` and `prop.table`, but `CrossTable` in the `gmodels` package might give you results even closer to SAS. [See this link](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/frequencies.html).

Also, to generate "descriptive statistics for multiple variables at once," you would use the `summary` function; e.g., `summary(mydata)`.

Comment: In addition, I warmly recommend the [vcd](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vcd/) package, but see the accompanying vignette: [Working with categorical data with R and the vcd and vcdExtra packages](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vcdExtra/vignettes/vcd-tutorial.pdf).

Answer (score 9):

Summarising data in base R is just a headache. This is one of the areas where SAS works quite well. For R, I recommend the `plyr` package.

In SAS:

```
/* tabulate by a and b, with summary stats for x and y in each cell */
proc summary data=dat nway;
  class a b;
  var x y;
  output out=smry mean(x)=xmean mean(y)=ymean var(y)=yvar;
run;
```

with `plyr`:

```
smry <- ddply(dat, .(a, b), summarise, xmean=mean(x), ymean=mean(y), yvar=var(y))
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't use SAS; so I can't comment on whether the following replicate `SAS PROC FREQ`, but these are two quick strategies for describing variables in a data.frame that I often use:

- `describe` in `Hmisc` provides a useful summary of variables including numeric and non-numeric data
- `describe` in `psych` provides descriptive statistics for numeric data

#### R Example

```
> library(MASS) # provides dataset called "survey"
> library(Hmisc) # Hmisc describe
> library(psych) # psych describe
```

The following is the output of `Hmisc` `describe`:

```
> Hmisc::describe(survey)
survey 

 12  Variables      237  Observations
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sex 
      n missing  unique 
    236       1       2 

Female (118, 50%), Male (118, 50%) 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Wr.Hnd 
      n missing  unique    Mean     .05     .10     .25     .50     .75     .90     .95 
    236       1      60   18.67   16.00   16.50   17.50   18.50   19.80   21.15   22.05 

lowest : 13.0 14.0 15.0 15.4 15.5, highest: 22.5 22.8 23.0 23.1 23.2 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NW.Hnd 
      n missing  unique    Mean     .05     .10     .25     .50     .75     .90     .95 
    236       1      68   18.58   15.50   16.30   17.50   18.50   19.72   21.00   22.22 

lowest : 12.5 13.0 13.3 13.5 15.0, highest: 22.7 23.0 23.2 23.3 23.5 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ABBREVIATED OUTPUT]
```

Then below is the output of `psych` `describe` for the numeric variables:

```
> psych::describe(survey[,sapply(survey, class) %in% c("numeric", "integer") ])
       var   n   mean    sd median trimmed   mad    min   max range  skew kurtosis   se
Wr.Hnd   1 236  18.67  1.88  18.50   18.61  1.48  13.00  23.2 10.20  0.18     0.36 0.12
NW.Hnd   2 236  18.58  1.97  18.50   18.55  1.63  12.50  23.5 11.00  0.02     0.51 0.13
Pulse    3 192  74.15 11.69  72.50   74.02 11.12  35.00 104.0 69.00 -0.02     0.41 0.84
Height   4 209 172.38  9.85 171.00  172.19 10.08 150.00 200.0 50.00  0.22    -0.39 0.68
Age      5 237  20.37  6.47  18.58   18.99  1.61  16.75  73.0 56.25  5.16    34.53 0.42
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check out my [**summarytools**](https://github.com/dcomtois/summarytools) package ([CRAN link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/summarytools/index.html)) which includes a codebook-like function, with markdown and html formatting options.

```
install.packages("summarytools")
library(summarytools)
dfSummary(CO2, style = "grid", plain.ascii = TRUE)
```

#### Dataframe Summary

### CO2

```
+------------+---------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------+
| Variable   | Properties    | Stats / Values                      | Freqs, % Valid     | N Valid   |
+============+===============+=====================================+====================+===========+
| Plant      | type:integer  | 1. Qn1                              | 1: 7 (8.3%)        | 84/84     |
|            | class:ordered | 2. Qn2                              | 2: 7 (8.3%)        | (100.0%)  |
|            | + factor      | 3. Qn3                              | 3: 7 (8.3%)        |           |
|            |               | 4. Qc1                              | 4: 7 (8.3%)        |           |
|            |               | 5. Qc3                              | 5: 7 (8.3%)        |           |
|            |               | 6. Qc2                              | 6: 7 (8.3%)        |           |
|            |               | 7. Mn3                              | 7: 7 (8.3%)        |           |
|            |               | 8. Mn2                              | 8: 7 (8.3%)        |           |
|            |               | 9. Mn1                              | 9: 7 (8.3%)        |           |
|            |               | 10. Mc2                             | 10: 7 (8.3%)       |           |
|            |               | ... 2 other levels                  | others: 14 (16.7%) |           |
+------------+---------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------+
| Type       | type:integer  | 1. Quebec                           | 1: 42 (50%)        | 84/84     |
|            | class:factor  | 2. Mississippi                      | 2: 42 (50%)        | (100.0%)  |
+------------+---------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------+
| Treatment  | type:integer  | 1. nonchilled                       | 1: 42 (50%)        | 84/84     |
|            | class:factor  | 2. chilled                          | 2: 42 (50%)        | (100.0%)  |
+------------+---------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------+
| conc       | type:double   | mean (sd) = 435 (295.92)            | 95: 12 (14.3%)     | 84/84     |
|            | class:numeric | min < med < max = 95 < 350 < 1000   | 175: 12 (14.3%)    | (100.0%)  |
|            |               | IQR (CV) = 500 (0.68)               | 250: 12 (14.3%)    |           |
|            |               |                                     | 350: 12 (14.3%)    |           |
|            |               |                                     | 500: 12 (14.3%)    |           |
|            |               |                                     | 675: 12 (14.3%)    |           |
|            |               |                                     | 1000: 12 (14.3%)   |           |
+------------+---------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------+
| uptake     | type:double   | mean (sd) = 27.21 (10.81)           | 76 distinct values | 84/84     |
|            | class:numeric | min < med < max = 7.7 < 28.3 < 45.5 |                    | (100.0%)  |
|            |               | IQR (CV) = 19.23 (0.4)              |                    |           |
+------------+---------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------+
```

**EDIT**

In newer versions of **summarytools**, the `freq()` function (which produces straightforward frequency tables, more to-the-point as regards to the original question) accepts data frames as well as single variables. For cross-tabulations (which **proc freq** also does), see the `ctable()` function.

```
freq(CO2)
```

#### Frequencies

CO2$Plant

**Type**: Ordered Factor

```
          Freq   % Valid    % Valid Cum   % Total    % Total Cum
    Qn1      7      8.33           8.33      8.33           8.33
    Qn2      7      8.33          16.67      8.33          16.67
    Qn3      7      8.33          25.00      8.33          25.00
    Qc1      7      8.33          33.33      8.33          33.33
    Qc3      7      8.33          41.67      8.33          41.67
    Qc2      7      8.33          50.00      8.33          50.00
    Mn3      7      8.33          58.33      8.33          58.33
    Mn2      7      8.33          66.67      8.33          66.67
    Mn1      7      8.33          75.00      8.33          75.00
    Mc2      7      8.33          83.33      8.33          83.33
    Mc3      7      8.33          91.67      8.33          91.67
    Mc1      7      8.33         100.00      8.33         100.00
   <NA>      0                               0.00         100.00
  Total     84    100.00         100.00    100.00         100.00
```

CO2$Type

**Type**: Factor

```
                Freq   % Valid    % Valid Cum   % Total    % Total Cum
       Quebec     42     50.00          50.00     50.00          50.00
  Mississippi     42     50.00         100.00     50.00         100.00
         <NA>      0                               0.00         100.00
        Total     84    100.00         100.00    100.00         100.00
```

CO2$Treatment

**Type**: Factor

```
               Freq   % Valid    % Valid Cum   % Total    % Total Cum
  nonchilled     42     50.00          50.00     50.00          50.00
     chilled     42     50.00         100.00     50.00         100.00
        <NA>      0                               0.00         100.00
       Total     84    100.00         100.00    100.00         100.00
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the **codebook** function from **{EPICALC}** which gives summary statistics for a numeric variable and a frequency table with level labels and codes for factors. http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Epicalc_Book.pdf (see p.50)
Moreover, this is very useful because it provides sd for quantitative variables.

Enjoy !

[image: sample output]

Comment: +1 (from earlier). I really like the way `codebook()` lays this out. 1 issue is that `na`s are dropped, which you may want included in your output. 1 way to deal w/ this (at least w/ factors) is to use [?recode.is.na](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/epicalc/html/recode.html) 1st (eg, to "missing"); for numeric variables, you can create a new variable immediately to the left of the column w/ a logical value based on `is.na()`, then run `codebook()`. It is a bit of a kluge, though.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the suggestions everyone. I ended up using either table or Rcmdr's numSummary function plus apply:

```
apply(dataframe[,c('need_rbcs','need_platelets','need_ffp')],2,table)
```

This works pretty well and is not too inconvenient. However I will definitely give some of these other solutions a try!